# SQL Server : convert datetime in place in table

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Basically I inherited a rather large table which has a few columns with dates formatted as `varchar(10)` of '##.##.####' (day.month.year). I would like to convert these columns to `Datetime` columns for that specific date.

Is there anyway to convert these in place on SQL Server (through a single set of SQL queries), instead of SELECTing each record in some programming language, converting the date and then UPDATEing back as `Datetime` (perhaps to a different column)?

Comment: Add a datetime field and do this                                                                                                          `update TableName set newfield =
 (select cast(substring(oldfield,4,2) + '/' + left(oldfield,2) +  '/' + right(oldfield,4) as datetime))`

Comment: @JimHewitt you should make that an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need in `...=(select...)` The action is simple and straightforward.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD NewDateColumn DATETIME

update YourTable set NewDateColumn = convert(date, OldDateColumn, 104) 
--Magic 104 is for dd.MM.yyyy date format
```

That's all.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

How about this as an alternative to Jim's comment. First add new `DATE` column:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD NewDateColumn DATETIME
```

Then to `UPDATE` (I suppose you would want to use the same standard you've been using):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.NewDateColumn = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, OldDateColumn, 104) 
                        FROM YourTable ta WHERE t.ID = ta.ID)
FROM YourTable t
```

For someone that might want to get it from the German standard to the U.S. standard:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.NewDateColumn = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                      CONVERT(DATE, OldDateColumn, 104) 
                                      ,101)
                        FROM YourTable ta WHERE t.ID = ta.ID)
FROM YourTable t
```

This is assuming you do have an `ID` column.